# Number theory proof explanation

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation, modules, reduced-residue-system

[image]So I've been reading [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82515789.pdf), and I'm trying to understand the proof of the main theorem (I want to use it in different problem, but first I need to fully understand how this kind of proof works). I have some difficulties with:

1. if $u+v$, $t_i , t_f$ are random, or they're some specific numbers
2. why $q_{ij} $ and $ q'_{ij} $ do exist
3. why do $ q_{ij} \neq p_{fg} $, $ q'_{ij} \neq p_{fg} $ hold (it's at the beginning of the proof, first paragraph)

Edit: I added picture of the theorem, and the beginnig of proof.

Comment: Please write out the main theorem, notational definitions and make this question self contained.

Comment: I added the photo, because the whole proof is too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value $u+v$ is arbitrary, it just refers to the fact that there are $u$ coverings that satisfy the $r_{ij} \equiv 2^{a_{ij}} - k_i \mod p_{ij}$ equation, and $v$ coverings that satisfy the $r_{ij} \equiv -2^{a_{ij}} - k_j \mod p_{ij}$ equation. Then $t_i$ is the size of the $i$th covering (and $t_f$ is the same for the $f$th covering).

The existence of $q_{ij}$ and $q'_{ij}$ is claimed via reference [5], which is a 1904 paper you can read on [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2007263). I took a quick look at the paper and I think it's a direct consequence of the main theorem in it, but someone more well-versed in number theory can probably explain it (the paper points to two other references for the same claim, but it looks like they're in languages I don't speak).

Likewise, the claim that $q_{ij} \neq p_{fg}$ appears to be by construction of Theorem III from the 1904 paper.